# Global variables, Class or nested function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nested, global-variables

Can Anyone please tell me the difference between these 3 snippets? I am facing these global and local variable access issue. No idea what is ({counter}). and why others are not giving me output.

```js
var counter = 3;

function example() {
  let counter = 50;
  console.log(this.counter);
  console.log(counter);
};

example();
```

Output :

```
Undefined
50
```

VS

```js
var counter = 3;

var example = function() {
  let counter = 50;
  console.log(this.counter);
  console.log(counter);
}

example.call(counter);
```

Output :

```
Undefined
50
```

VS

```js
var counter = 3;

var example = function() {
  let counter = 50;
  console.log(this.counter);
  console.log(counter);
}

example.call({counter});
```

Output

```
3
50
```

Comment: Also log `this` inside the function.

Comment: which one exactly?

Comment: The first snippet doesn't output "Undefined".

Comment: `{counter}` is shorthand for `{counter:counter}`

Comment: Also ``this:`` [JavaScript Function call()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp) with a section on ``this:`` **What is this?**

Comment: In example 2, the value of `this` is `3`, so the value of `this.counter` is `3.counter`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the undefined output in your second snipet of code is that the call() method of Function object calls the function and sets this value for the calling function as the first parameter.
For example, let us take the following code:

```
function test(){
  return this;
}
const returnVal = test.call({a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'});
consoel.log(returnVal) // prints out {a:'a',b:'b',c:'c'}
```

In this example, we have set the "this" value for the calling function to an object. This is the reason why it prints out the object.
In your case, you are setting the "this" value as the counter variable, which holds a value of 3. When you try to access the this value, JavaScript associates the "this" value to be a Number object. We can test this out by writing the following code:

```
var counter = 3;
function test(){
  return this.__proto__ // This access the prototype of the instances of Number object;
}
const returnVal = test.call(counter);
console.log(returnVal) // Prints the prototype of the instances of Number object.
```

As you have seen, the JavaScript engine will convert a primitive to an object in the call method of the Function constructor.
To explain your third snipet, it outputs 3 and 50 simply because you have passed an object to the call method of the Function object. So in plain English, your code reads like this:

1. Create the counter variable and make this variable a property of the window object, which has a value of 3.
2. Create the example variable and set it to an anymnoumus function.
3. Execute the example function with the call method, passing an object as its this value.
4. Execute each line within the function.
5. Create another variable counter and set this equal to 50.
6. In your second line you are loggin out the counter variable.

```
console.log(this.counter) // Js will treat this as the variable we passed to the call method.
```

7. Finally log the counter variable inside the function scope.
   I hope this is clear enough for you.
   If you want to learn more about the call method, here is a good article:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, a global variable will always be const, because it will never change, with respect to the three exercises,

In the first one, it gives you 3 and 50 because you are assigning var to your counter variable outside the function, inside the function you assign another value, that's why it generates changes in the block since var is not global.

In the second you are creating a function without parameters, and when calling it you are adding it as a parameter (counter) without being unstructured, which causes your previous variable to come out undefined.

**"example.call(counter);"**

In the third, I see that your code is unstructured, for that reason it is throwing information at the output of the variable

**"example.call({counter});"**